# Implementing "deleting algorithm" for linked list type data structures

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list, delete-operator

Here is a delete function I have written to delete some nodes from my linked list when needed.

- the linked list is stored as alphabetically ordered

Using below function, when I try to delete the very first element of a linked list (named head), I get an runtime error when I am trying to print the linked list (using the print function) and the program crashes. I am aware that this is probably caused by not creating a new head node. But I do not know how to solve this. This is probably very simple but couldn't figure out. Can you please help :)

this is the delete function:

```
 void deleteName(someStruct * &head, string name)
{
    someStruct * ptr = head;
    someStruct * previous;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "empty";
    }
    else if(head->name == name)
    {
        ptr = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete head;
    }
    else
    {
        while (ptr -> name != name)
        {
            previous = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        previous->next = ptr->next;
        delete ptr;
    }
}
```

this is the print function:

```
void Print(someStruct * head)
{
    someStruct * pointer = head;
    //List is empty
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "List is empty" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while(pointer != NULL)
        {
            cout << pointer->name;
            cout << pointer->points << endl;
            pointer = pointer->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a [MCVE].

Comment: When the node you want to delete is the list head, you have a bug there that will lead to *undefined behavior*. Think about what you `delete`...

Comment: `delete head;` should probably be `delete ptr;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if(head->name == name)
{
    ptr = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete head;
}
```

This:

1. saves the old value of `head` to `ptr`, which is correct
2. advances the inout param `head`, which is also correct
3. completely ignores `ptr`, which contains the old node you want to delete, and instead deletes the current list head, leaving the inout param `head` pointing to a deleted node.

   This bit isn't correct.

Just change `delete head` to `delete ptr`.

---

Note for future reference: the *good* way to structure this is to use a local sentinel node which doesn't need to be deleted. This removes your special case for `head` (by adding the invariant that your temporary head can never be removed) and simplifies the code.

```
void deleteName(someStruct * &head, string name)
{
    if(!head) {
        cout << "empty";
        return;
    }

    someStruct tmphead;
    tmphead.next = head;

    for (someStruct *prev = &tmphead; prev->next; prev = prev->next) {
        if (prev->next->name == name) {
            auto todelete = prev->next;
            prev->next = todelete->next;
            delete todelete;
            // if there can be only one match, just bail out
            break;
            // otherwise, if there can be many, go round again
            // but remember to check whether prev->next is null
            // if (!prev->next) break;
        }
    }

    head = tmphead.next;
}
```

If your `someStruct` is too large or complex to use a temporary head like this, you can do the same with a temporary local head pointer, and make `prev` a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The `delete head` in `else if` block is the problem.

Change the block to this :

```
else if(head->name == name) {
    //ptr = head; You don't have to. You already have initialized ptr with head
    head = head->next;
    delete ptr; //Delete prt not head, head is now the next node which you assigned in previous line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
else if(head->name == name){
   ptr = head;
   head = head -> next;
   delete ptr;  // change to this statement n you're good to go
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.